# Calling member function via pointer C++, object is null?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nullpointerexception, singly-linked-list

I have a pointer to a ListNode object `sum_ptr`, which points to `sum`. When I call the `append` method via `sum_ptr`, I get a segfault. Looking at gdb, I am seeing that "this" is 0x0 in the call to append, which does not make sense. Does anyone know why the `sum` object would be null at the point at which the append method is called? Thank you!

```
  ListNode sum;
  ListNode* sum_ptr = &sum;
  
  const ListNode* l1_ptr = &l1;
  const ListNode* l2_ptr = &l2;

  int c_over = 0;
  while(l1_ptr != nullptr && l2_ptr != nullptr){
    int temp_sum = l1_ptr->val + l2_ptr->val + c_over;
    temp_sum = temp_sum >= 10 ? temp_sum - 10 : temp_sum;
    c_over = temp_sum >= 10 ? 1 : 0;

    sum_ptr->append(temp_sum);
    sum_ptr = sum_ptr->next;
    
    l1_ptr = l1_ptr->next;
    l2_ptr = l2_ptr->next;
  }
```

Append method:

```
void ListNode::append(int v){
  if(this->val == INT_MIN){
    this->val = v;
  }
  else{
    ListNode *e = new ListNode();
    e->val = v; 
    ListNode* n = this;
    while(n->next != nullptr){
      n = n->next;
    }
    n->next = e;
  }
}
```

Comment: If `this->val == INT_MIN` is `true` in `append` then `n->next` won't be set so it might be `nullptr` when you perform `sum_ptr = sum_ptr->next;`.

Comment: After `sum_ptr->append(temp_sum); sum_ptr = sum_ptr->next;`, you never  check if `sum_ptr` is null or not.

Comment: @ianwt after this statement temp_sum = temp_sum >= 10 ? temp_sum - 10 : temp_sum; temp_sum is less than 10. So the next statement 
    c_over = temp_sum >= 10 ? 1 : 0; does not make a sense.

Comment: @ianwt Also this condition   if(this->val == INT_MIN){
    this->val = v;
  } does not make a sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the problem is the following.

You declared a node using the default constructor.

```
ListNode sum;
```

It seems that the default constructor sets the data member `next`  to `nullptr` and the data member `val` to the value `INT_MIN` (that does not make a sense).

Then you are calling the member function `append` the first time using the pointer `sum_ptr`.

```
ListNode* sum_ptr = &sum;
//...
sum_ptr->append(temp_sum);
```

The member function `append` in this case just changes the data member `val`.

```
void ListNode::append(int v){
  if(this->val == INT_MIN){
    this->val = v;
  }
  //...
```

And then you are reassigning the pointer in the while loop

```
sum_ptr = sum_ptr->next;
```

So now the pointer `sum_ptr` has the value of the data member `sum.next` that is equal to `nullptr`. And you are using this null pointer in a next call of the member function `append` that results in undefined behavior.

Also pay attention to that for example this pair of statements

```
temp_sum = temp_sum >= 10 ? temp_sum - 10 : temp_sum;
c_over = temp_sum >= 10 ? 1 : 0;
```

does not make a sense because after execution of the first statement `temp_sum` is always less than 10. So the variable `c_over` always will be set to 0. You need at least to exchange these statements.

Comment: My issue is that my class did not have a notion of an empty linked list, so my approach was to default initialize to INT_MIN to represent an empty list. I've come up with a better approach which is to create a wrapper class for my ListNode, which will have a head data member that is default initialized to nullptr. This represents an empty list. Thanks for your help!